# Can you give me some clarification about the REST architecture?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, soap

I am studying for a developer certification and I have some doubt related to the general concept of **REST** and **REST Web Services**.

From what I can understand **REST** is more related to software\network architecture style consisting of guidelines and best practices for creating scalable web services respect to a specific technology (differently from **SOAP** that is a specific implemented network protocol).

The first doubt is: "is **REST** related only to web services implementation or can be related also to other purposes? If it could be related to other purposes what are?

So from what I can understand using this **REST** style the messagges are send and receive directly using the **HTTP** protocol without using an intermediate protocol as **SOAP**.

I know that **REST** is statless (does not maintain information about previous states) so if I use the **REST** style I can't use the **Http Session** or **coockies** to mantain informations about what happens before. If it is true, why? what is the benefit of a statles managment? What is the difference with SOAP? Is SOAP statefull? (it seems to me not but I can say wrong things).

Using **REST** style the **resources** are modelled as **noun**, for example:

```
http://mybank.com/banking/accounts/123456789
```

And then I can perform a limited set of operations on these resources, operations described by: **GET**, **PUT**, **POST**, **DELETE**

Reading on the course documentation it say that these operations are the default operation in case of the architecture works over **Http** protocol. So are these operations the only operations that I can perform or can be used others? Can you explain me this thing?

Maybe I have a big gap in the Http protocol knowledge, I only know that Http protocol only supports the **POST** and **GET** operations. So what exatly are these **PUT** and **DELETE** operations? Are Http protocol specific operations as **GET** and **POST**? What is the difference between **PUT** and **POST**? and why **REST** architecture use **PUT** instead **POST**?

Tnx

Comment: Less **random** bold **please**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST describes guidelines and best practices to design an efficient architecture for the Web.

Can I suggest you to read these two posts? I think that they could help to answer deeply your questions about resources, operations, representations...

- https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/ - Designing a Web API (i.e. RESTful Web services)
- https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/ - How to handle security for RESTful Web services

Yes, normally RESTful applications are stateless. This means that you should keep states on the server-side. In the case of security, you need to authenticate users at each request. That said, since Cookies are part of HTTP, you could leverage them within your application.

Hope it helps,
Thierry